# WooCommerce Memberships. In admin list view of Members, how do I add "user ID" column

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-memberships

I am using the WooCommerce Memberships plugin.

In the admin dashboard, when I go to WooCommerce > Members there is a list view which has the column headers:

Name, Email, Plan,  Team, Status, Member since, Expires

I would like to add the USER ID to this column. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Modified some code I found online [here](https://github.com/skyverge/wc-plugins-snippets/blob/master/woocommerce-memberships/admin/user-memberships-add-role-column.php). This should work for the original ask.

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-wc_user_membership_columns', function( $columns ) {

    $userID_column = array( 'id' => __( 'User ID', 'woocommerce-memberships' ) );

    if ( isset( $columns['title'] ) ) {
        $columns = sv_wc_array_insert_after( $columns, 'title', $userID_column );
    } else {
        $columns = array_merge( $columns, $userID_column );
    }

    return $columns;

}, 20 ); 

add_action( 'manage_wc_user_membership_posts_custom_column', function( $column, $user_membership_id ) {

if ( 'id' === $column ) {

    $user_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $user_membership_id );
    $user    = get_userdata( $user_id );

    if ( $user ) {
  echo $user_id;
    } else {
        echo '&ndash;';
    }
}
}, 20, 2 );

if ( ! function_exists( 'sv_wc_array_insert_after' ) ) :

/**
 * Insert the given element after the given key in the array
 *
 * Sample usage:
 * array( 'item_1' => 'foo', 'item_2' => 'bar' )
 *
 * array_insert_after( $array, 'item_1', array( 'item_1.5' => 'w00t' ) )
 *
 * becomes
 * array( 'item_1' => 'foo', 'item_1.5' => 'w00t', 'item_2' => 'bar' )
 *
 * @param array $array array to insert the given element into
 * @param string $insert_key key to insert given element after
 * @param array $element element to insert into array
 * @return array
 */
function sv_wc_array_insert_after( Array $array, $insert_key, Array $element ) {

    $new_array = array();

    foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {

        $new_array[ $key ] = $value;

        if ( $insert_key == $key ) {

            foreach ( $element as $k => $v ) {
                $new_array[ $k ] = $v;
            }
        }
    }

    return $new_array;
}
endif;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
add_filter('manage_edit-wc_user_membership_columns', 'customize_columns');

function customize_columns($columns) {


    $columns['UID'] = __('USER ID', 'woocommerce-memberships');

    return $columns;
}



add_action('manage_wc_user_membership_posts_custom_column', 'custom_column_content');

function custom_column_content($column, $post_id) {

    $user_membership = wc_memberships_get_user_membership($post_id);
    If(!$user_membership) return;
    $userid = $user_membership->get_user_id();

    switch ($column) {

        case 'UID':
            echo $userid;
            break;
    }
}
```

**Tested OK with WooCommerce 3.5.6**

Comment: I tried this and it added the USER ID column, but all the data was missing, please see screenshot below showing the column headers but there are no rows underneath[below showing the column headers but there are no rows underneath][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgAbA.jpg

Comment: Yes I will copy it below. Thank you!

Comment: I had the same issues as @Bec9999